# How Do I Convert an Array of Characters To Integers?

Tags: c

I am Just a begineer in C Programming. While solving a programming assignement I came across the need to convert an array of `unsigned char` to `integer`.

For Example:

```
unsigned char x[]="567";
unsigned char y[]="94";
```

Now I have to add the integer values in both `x` and `y`. That is:

```
int sum=661;
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `atoi()` .

Comment: Unless the assignment intends for you to handle arbitrarily large numbers stored this way. Then you need to implement decimal add-and-carry like you learned in grade school...

Comment: But using atoi I got This error" Cannot convert unsigned char* to const char*.

Comment: You can cast the unsignedness away; that doesn't mean much when using `char` to store characters (as opposed to bytes).

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MSC34-C.+Do+not+use+deprecated+or+obsolescent+functions

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options if you use standard library. The first is [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)  function from `stdlib.h` and second is [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)function from `stdio.h`.

Here are examples:

**atoi()**

```
char number_string[] = "47";
int number;

number = atoi(number_string);
```

**sscanf()**

```
char number_string[] = "47";
int number;
int return;

return = sscanf(number_string, "%d", &number);
/* it would be good idea to check the return value here */
```

`sscanf()` gives you a better error handling. Return value of `sscanf()` determines  how many items were succesfully read (how many variables were filled). If there was an input failure, EOF is returned.

`atoi()` returns 0 if no valid conversion could be performed.